# Understanding the behind the scenes of the canDeactivate guard in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently learning all about the guards in Angular, and I am wondering why can't there be class where's there's a deactivate method and just import the class and use deactivate?

The commented code should explain my concern.

```js
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
    // We create an interface with a method called 'canDeactivate'
}
```

```js
export class canDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
    /*
        I can't wrap my head around how the canDeactivate interface resolves to our own interface, and why
        we can't just use the canDeactivate method inside the canDeactivate interface? If this has to do with
        the internal structure of Angular, then just say so and I'll deal with it. 
    */
    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate, 
        currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, 
        nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean  | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        return true
    }

}
```

Again, if this has to do with the internal structure of Angular, then just say so. However, there has to be clear reason we can't just directly use the `Deactivate` interface to do the work instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure `canDeactivate` guard for specific route/routes, route also has component type reference, component instance will be passed to configured guard as first parameter. There is no type check in router config so component and guard are only connected by config itself.

So you can either create separate guards for each component type or create single interface and make all your components implement it.